# Reference Request: How to Solve PDE with ANN

Tags: neural-networks, differential-equations

I've recently heard that it's possible to approximate the solutions of PDEs with ANNs.  However, upon looking it up on the Google, it seems that I can't find a detailed example in R (or even a detailed example of the algorithm for that matter).  Does anyone have any references/links?

Comment: Does this help you? http://lmgtfy.com/?q=approximating+pde+solutions+with+neural+networks

Comment: This article perhaps? https://becominghuman.ai/neural-networks-for-solving-differential-equations-fa230ac5e04c